Windows Server 2019 ignores disconnection timers
I have to set different conditions of RDP session time limits per user, but my Windows server 2019 ignores this configuration tool:

What should I do?
Logged off users are never disconnected by the server.

Does this answer your question? How can I have multiple active Windows sessions simultaneously?
